# Overflowing element showing in adjacent card in react-responsive-carousel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-responsive-carousel

I'm using react-responsive-carousel. What I need to accomplish is that I want to show half part of  absolute positioned image in a carousel card. I want to hide its overflowing part when it's static but need to show the complete image while scrolling.

Currently, I'm using the `hidden` tailwind class because otherwise, it shows the remaining part in the adjacent card which seems like a bug in design.
I tried to utilize `onSwipeStart` prop as well in order to remove the "hidden" class with the help of a useState hook when it's being scrolled . But it's not changing the state.

**Edit:** It's actually changing the state while scrolling through the mouse, but not working when it's scrolling through navigation dots. Can you please suggest any prop similar to `onSwipeStart` that could trigger when carousel-dot is clicked?
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [isMoving, setIsMoving] = useState(false);
  const onSwipeStart = () => {
    setIsMoving(true);
    alert("its moving")
  };

  const onSwipeEnd = () => {
    setIsMoving(false);
  };

  const arrowStyle = {
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    width: "fit-content",
    borderRadius: "2rem",
    padding: "0.5rem",
    color: "white"
  };
  const prevArrowStyle = {
    ...arrowStyle,
    position: "absolute",
    top: "35%",
    zIndex: "50"
  };

  const nextArrowStyle = {
    ...arrowStyle,
    position: "absolute",
    top: "35%",
    right: "0"
  };

  const myArrowPrev = (onClickHandler, hasPrev, label) =>
    hasPrev && (
      <p onClick={onClickHandler} style={prevArrowStyle}>
        Previous
      </p>
    );

  const myArrowNext = (onClickHandler, hasNext, label) =>
    hasNext && (
      <p onClick={onClickHandler} style={nextArrowStyle}>
        Next
      </p>
    );

  const userIconStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    left: "-8%",
    width: "5rem"
    // Add any other styles you want here
  };

  const boxStyle = {
    position: "relative",
    overflow: !isMoving ? "hidden" : "visible"
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Carousel
        renderArrowPrev={myArrowPrev}
        renderArrowNext={myArrowNext}
        infiniteLoop={true}
        onSwipeStart={onSwipeStart}
        onSwipeEnd={onSwipeEnd}
        swipeable={true}
      >
        <div style={boxStyle}>
          <img src="./user-circle.svg" alt="icon" style={userIconStyle}></img>
          <img
            src="./img-1.jpg"
            alt="carousel-item"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          ></img>
        </div>
        <div style={boxStyle}>
          <img src="./user-circle.svg" alt="icon" style={userIconStyle}></img>
          <img
            src="./img-2.jpg"
            alt="carousel-item"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          ></img>
        </div>
        <div style={boxStyle}>
          <img src="./user-circle.svg" alt="icon" style={userIconStyle}></img>
          <img
            src="./img-3.jpg"
            alt="carousel-item"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          ></img>
        </div>
      </Carousel>
      <div>{isMoving ? "its moving" : "it's not moving"}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this is the codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/carouseloverflow-wysl6k?file=/src/App.js:0-2468

Comment: But if you want to show it while scrolling, it will then of course appear on the right & left side, and when it stops is the right hand side to disappear?,.  Wouldn't that look a bit janky?

Comment: Yes, it might be. Please suggest if you've something else to try. I just want it to show full while scrolling.